# Hello windows camera as a web camera on Linux | Philips 272s1mh/00

Tags: linux-mint, monitors, camera

I recently bought a Philips 272s1mh/00 27" monitor with the idea of using it as an additional monitor for my work HP laptop with Windows 11 pro and at the same time for my Dell Vostro laptop with Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.1.

I do not want to use the monitor's Hello Windows camera for facial recognition nor to login to any of my systems, as it was primarily meant for - I'd prefer it as just a regular web camera.

Is it possible to achieve this? I cannot find any data anywhere online. Has anyone had a similar experience?

My Linux system does not see it, as it is not connected to the monitor via cable. It is integrated into the monitor, as a retractable popup device.

When I start Cheese (camera software), my integrated Dell laptop camera light once blinks, and then shuts down, just tells me it encountered an error. When I open preferences in Cheese, it only offers my laptop integrated camera.

Should I just continue installing Linux camera software one by one, and try resolving this issue in a trial and error manner, or is there a more reliable, systematic approach, such as someone who has already resolved a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Windows Hello* face authentication requires a camera that can sense near infrared light (instead or in addition to regular visible light), with an optional IR strobe light to enhance the resulting infra-red images.

The camera may or may not also work as a regular (visible-light) web camera. I have a Tobii 5 eye tracker (for use with flight simulator games): it also doubles as a Windows Hello face authentication camera, since an IR camera is part of the eye tracker functionality, but it apparently cannot take visible light pictures at all.

In Linux, my IR camera appears as a `/dev/video0` device controlled by the `uvcvideo` driver, but most Linux webcam programs are confused by it, as apparently the camera has some IR-specific extra attributes and/or some attributes regarding regular visible light are encoded as "not applicable" in the camera's metadata, and the webcam programs and/or the `uvcvideo` driver are not expecting that.

I think my previous OS release, Debian 10, had some program that managed to get a black-and-white IR image from the camera (with a surprisingly poor resolution!), but my current Debian 11 doesn't seem to be able to do that (or maybe it was some specific `uvcvideo` driver testing utility that I built from source to test the camera, and then forgot the details).

Although the camera is wired internally to the display, it's probably still an  USB device. If you connect the USB cable between the display and the laptop to allow the use of the USB hub integrated to the display, the same connection should also provide access to the camera.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I somehow supposed that any cable connection, such as HDMI or VGA, between the monitor and the laptop would suffice, but it wasn't enough. A usb cable connection between the monitor and the laptop did its magic. Thank you very much.